# Understanding VPN connection and virtual network architecture in Azure for accessing VM without public IP

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am new to Azure

in my organization we use VPN, We need VPN connection for access the VM and we can't able to access without that VPN

and my virtual machine dosen't have any public IP i uploaded the picture you can see below

Here My question is How it's work with VPN Connection only,

and what type of virtual network they implemented

[image]

Need to know networking architecture using in my org
and know how it's working

Comment: If you could give us a bit of information that would be great. IP's are assigned by default on the main screen of your virtual machine resource. Did you try refreshing it? This sometimes could be the case. What type of Operating System did you use? Did you tick _none_ in the _inbound port rules_ during the installation of the VM? You may want to re-create your VM if that's the case.

Comment: Hi @Mitchell i refreshed but there is no public address they are using Private ip for RDP, and we are using Windows (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter)

Comment: Ok so I was able to reproduce your VM, and under the _connect_ tab I can see a public IP address. Can you check?

Comment: I checked i don't have permission @Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my environment Created virtual machine without using public Ip like below:

[image]

> **Mostly In organizations public Ip isn’t recommended for security purposes. Public IP addresses are risky from a security standpoint. To access vm without using public Ip you can Azure Bastion service or VPN connection. Microsoft that allows users to access internal VMs without using an external IP address on the internal virtual machines.**

Generate a client certificate like below:

```c
#Root Certificate: 
 $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature `
-Subject "CN=NameofRoot" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
-HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 `
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign

#Client Certificate:

New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -DnsName P2SChildCert -KeySpec Signature `
-Subject "CN=Nameofclient" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
-HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 `
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" `
-Signer $cert -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2")
```

***Output***:

```
   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\My

Thumbprint                                Subject                                                                    
----------                                -------                                                                    
0E2927D5BEA1FB1A2321193C12DXXXXX       CN=imrp2sclient
```

[image]

Created a virtual network gateway and connected to my vpn like below:

[image]

[image]

Now, when I try to access my virtual machine using without public Ip I am able to connect to local machine with private Ip through the tunnel connected RDP successfully like below:

[image]

***References***:

[Connect a computer to a virtual network Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-classic-azure-portal)

[How to Access Azure VM from outside - Virtualization Howto](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2022/02/how-to-access-azure-vm-from-outside/)